# How to display just one element with same id

Tags: javascript, css, html, angular

This is my first question at stack overflow

i just wanted to know a simple solution for the following case

```
<div *ngFor="let d of w.event">
<div class="date" id="d.date" >
              <p>
                <span style="font-size:1.75em">{{d.date | date:'dd'}}</span>
                <br>
                <strong>&nbsp;{{d.date | date:'EEE'}}</strong>
              </p>
            </div>
```

the looped div can have the same id
I just want to display the first div with a particular date and ignore the rest
can this be achieved with CSS or JavaScript

Comment: Two elements can't have the same id.

Comment: In html it didn't accept two id's with same name

Comment: Having multiple attributes with the same ID is invalid HTML. You should fix your HTML instead.

Comment: is there a way to uniquely identify my div ? except using id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the same `id` on two elements. It's one of the few restrictions on `id`s.

You can use a class:

```
<div class="show">Yes</div> <div class="show">No</div>
```

...and then show either the first or second by using index 0 or index 1 after getting a list of matching elements:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".show");
list[0].style.display = "none"; // Hides the first one
// or
list[1].style.display = "none"; // Hides the second one
```

Some other thoughts:

1. Rather than using `style.display` as I did above, you might add a class that hides the element.

2. You might use separate `id`s (or classes) for the elements so you don't need to index, e.g.:

```
<div id="show-yes">Yes</div> <div id="show-no">No</div>
```

then

```
document.getElementById("show-yes").style.display = "none";
// or
document.getElementById("show-no").style.display = "none";
```

---

On all browsers in my experience, you can do the first thing above (with `querySelectorAll`) with your invalid HTML with a selector like `"[id=show]`, but **don't**. Fix the HTML instead.

---

In your question update, you show:

```
<div *ngFor="let d of w.event">
<div class="date" id="d.date" >
...
```

You've said you're aware of the fact you can't have multiple elements with the same `id`, so why code that? You can easily give them unique `id`s:

```
<div *ngFor="let d of w.event; let i = index">
<div class="date" id="d.date{{i}}" >
...
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am aware of the multiple id rule, but the reason for having a same id is because i will be getting the id dynamically binding to the html, some elements may have same id .. of which i want to avoid display

Comment: @AkashMahale: Again: You need to fix the code so you aren't producing elements with the same `id`. If you're aware of the issue, coding `<div *ngFor="let d of w.event" class="date" id="d.date" >` doesn't make much sense....?

Comment: the reason for that was... i want to show only the first div for example i want to display 30 March only once. if there are multiple 30 march.... i don't want them displayed

Comment: @AkashMahale: Then why loop?

Comment: im getting this from a json ... so i have to loop these events. if there are two events on the same day i need to display just once.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in HTML ID is a unique selector so one ID can be associate with only one element. if you want to achieve your desired functionality you have to assign different id for both DIV. and use javascript to hide and show DIV

```
<div id="showYes">Yes</div> <div id="showNo">No</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am aware of the multiple id rule, but the reason for having a same id is because i will be getting the id dynamically binding to the html, some elements may have same id .. of which i want to avoid display

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show one at a time you can go with `*ngIf` , as it will show only one at a time

```
<div id="show" *ngIf='your_status'>Yes</div> 
<div id="show" *ngIf='!your_status'>No</div>
```

---

After your question update , you can create custom filter that will only return unique date , so only first unique date will be shown

```
// CREATE A PIPE FILTER :
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'checkUniqueDate'})
export class UniqueDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(dataArray) {
    let dates = [];
    return dataArray.filter(data => {
        return if(dates.indexOf(data.date) === -1) {
            dates.push(data.date);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
  }
}

// TEMPLATE SIDE :
<div *ngFor="let d of (w.event | checkUniqueDate )">
```

Comment: Thank You for answering... but the div id i will be binding fro the json so i need a way to do that by using ngIF in just the div on my code

Answer (score 0):

Add the date in class also, then you can try below code

```
.YOUR_DATE{
    display:none
}
.YOUR_DATE:first-child{
    displany:inline
}
```

Comment: Only if you don't have two event on same date

Comment: can u show me the format for the class wrt to the above code

Comment: wrt to angular I think you need to create a custom directive where you can check the date with last stored one and then decide if you want show this div or not